# JPA2 entity unexpectedly remains managed after finishing transactional service layer method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

## Addition to the original post (16 december 2013)

Thanks for your comments so far!

The entity managers injected in the controller and in the service impl were only being added for debug purposes and to clarify my issue for stackoverflow.

I followed the suggestion of Andrei I, and added a service method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public boolean isManaged(MyEntity myEntity) {
    return em.contains(myEntity);
}
```

In the controller, I use this new isManaged() method, instead of injecting an EntityManager.

I retested the behavior and that's still the same: the entity remains attached outside the service method and changes to the entity are persisted to the DB. Only if I leave the controller method from which the service method was called, the entity becomes detached.

So help in understanding this behavior is still appreciated!

## Original post

I have a pretty standard Spring MVC web application, using JSP view technology, controllers, service layer methods, entities, Spring CrudRepository and JPA2/hibernate as ORM. Service layer methods run each within a transaction using the @Transactional annotation. I do not explicitly configure the PersistenceContextType, meaning that I use the default PersistenceContextType, which is TRANSACTION.

My question is about the managed state of entities. My understanding is that entities become detached after transaction commit, but this not seem to be the case! The behavior that I observe is the following (some code omitted for clarity):

```
public class DiningTableController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/diningTables/{diningTableId}/menuItems", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMenuItem() {
        1. invoke a service layer method which creates an entity object and invokes save() on it. The service method returns the saved entity
        2. check whether the saved entity is managed. Result: true
        3. change the value of a field of the entity (do not invoke save())
        4. invoke an arbitrary service method in which the entity is not referred to in any way
        5. manually verify in the database that the entity field value is indeed updated as a result of step 3.
        6. check whether the saved entity is managed. Result: true
        7. change the value of a field of the entity to a different value (do not invoke save())
        8. manually verify in the database that the entity field value is NOT updated as a result of step 3.
    }
```

After leaving the controller method, testing whether the entity is managed returns false. If after invoking the addMenuItem() method, I invoke another controller method that also invokes an arbitrary service method, I still do not see the value of step 7. in the database (which is according to epxectation as the entity state was now detached).

So the following seems to be the case:

- after leaving a service layer method, which is transactional (I can see in the log that this causes a commit to take place), the entity remains managed, which is unexpected.
- after leaving the controller method which was invoking the service layer method, the entity finally becomes detached.

A hypothesis is that it is caused by autocommit. By default autocommit is turned on. I turned it off using:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
```

This gives a warning "WARN : org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - HHH000144: hibernate.connection.autocommit = false breaks the EJB3 specification". The log shows in its behavior that autocommit is indeed turned off. This does not change the behavior. So my conclusion is that the observed behavior is not caused by autocommit.

Below I show the actual code.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@Controller
public class DiningTableController {

    private MyEntity savedMyEntity;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;       

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityService myEntityService;
@Autowired
private DiningTableService diningTableService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/diningTables/{diningTableId}/menuItems", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addMenuItem(
            @PathVariable("diningTableId") String diningTableId,
            @RequestParam String menuItemName, Model uiModel) {

        logger.info("*************BeforeServiceCall (attached=" + em.contains(savedMyEntity) + ")");
        savedMyEntity = myEntityService.doMyEntity();
        savedMyEntity.setSomeValue("ValueChangedOutsideTransaction");
        logger.info("*************ValueChangedOutsideTransaction (attached=" + em.contains(savedMyEntity) + ")");

        DiningTable diningTable = diningTableService.fetchWarmedUp(Long.valueOf(diningTableId));
        uiModel.addAttribute("diningTable", diningTable);

        savedMyEntity.setSomeValue("ValueChangedOutsideTransactionButAfterOtherTransaction");
        logger.info("*************ValueChangedOutsideTransactionButAfterOtherTransaction (attached=" + em.contains(savedMyEntity) + ")");

        return "redirect:/diningTables/" + diningTableId;
    }
}



@Service("diningTableService")
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = StateException.class)
public class DiningTableServiceImpl implements DiningTableService {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DiningTableServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    public MyEntity doMyEntity() {
        MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(5L, "ValueInitially");
        MyEntity savedMyEntity = myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
        logger.info("*************ValueInitially");
        savedMyEntity.setSomeValue("ValueChangedInsideTransaction");
        logger.info("*************ValueChangedInsideTransaction");
        return savedMyEntity;
    }

}




public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}



@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id") 
@Getter @Setter
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String someValue;

    public MyEntity() {
    }

    public MyEntity(Long id, String someValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Managed has nothing to do with a transaction, managed means only that it is attached to an `EntityManager`. Only a `clear` (or `close` of the `EntityManager` will cause a entity to become detached. Due to your injection of the `EntityManager` in your controller it remains open.

Comment: @M.Deinum that is not quire right. If you have a container-managed transaction-scoped persistence context (which is very often the case), then the managed entities get detached after transaction commit or roll-back.

Comment: @M.Deinum: JSR 317 Java Persistence API (Version 2.0, November 10 2009) says in Section 3.3.1 Transaction Commit:
"The managed entities of a transaction-scoped persistence context become detached when the transaction
commits; the managed entities of an extended persistence context remain managed." I use a transaction-scoped persistence context.

Comment: @ErcoArgante Well no you don't. `EntityManager` isn't transaction scoped, it would be true if you wouldn't inject the `EntityManager` in your controller then you would have a transaction-scoped persistence context, but now you don't. What you have now is an extended-scoped persistence context which is described in the same section of the JSR.

Comment: @ErcoArgante so you made sure, you don't have any EntityManagers injected in other places that in your Service (even if you don't use them)?  Also have you tried to set manually the `type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION` for your EntityManager (injected in your service: the only one actually)? Also have you tried to remove all tweaks you made for hibernate?

Comment: @Andrei I: I injected the EntityManager just for debug purposes, only to find out what the state of the entity is. It can be removed (I just did) without affecting the functionality of the application and also the observed problem. The application relies on annotation-driven Spring configuration, which means that you don't explicitly inject entity managers into the services. If it would be of help, I can add this Spring configuration to this post. I do have some hibernate configuration, but there's not much tweaking going on.

Comment: @M.Deinum Following your answer, I removed the explicitly injected entity manager in both the controller and the service. However, then I still see the behavior that changing the entity outside the service leads to a change in the database.

Comment: Is there anything else in your call chain opening an `EntityManager` like an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` or something alike. What you could do, to figure out where and when an `EntityManager` is opened, is enable DEBUG (or even TRACE) logging for `org.springframework` this should show you what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking wrong whether the entity is still managed. You shouldn't inject you EM in your controller. If you want to do that, make another request to your service and check it in there (something like `service.isManaged(mySavedEntity)`).

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses a proxy for the `EntityManager` which, when used, registers an `EntityManager` for the current thread. Springs transaction-management looks if there is already a thread bound `EntityManager`, which in your situtation is the case due to the injection inside the controller.

Now because there was alreadya thread bound `EntityManager` a new one for the transaction isn't created (as you might have expected) but the existing one is reused. Now because the existing one is reused the  transaction doesn't close/destroy the `EntityManager` but leaves it be, it will only commit the transaction.

To fix it and get real **transaction-scoped persistence context** behavior don't inject the `EntityManager` into your controller but create a method on your service to check if the object is managed. As @Andreii suggested in his answer/comment. This will create a new `EntityManager` for each transaction and not reuse the already thread bound `EntityManager`